# My dynamic button evaluates as soon as it's created. How do I stop this behavior?

Tags: function-construction, dynamic, scoping, date-and-time, autosave

I think I finally hit on the ***holy grail*** of buttons. With a very small footprint I coded a dynamic *AutoSave* button whose duration and frequency can be set all the while showing very useful dynamic real time information directly in the label (button name, countdown in seconds, "saved" and beep alert when saved) without freezing the `FrontEnd` or tying up the `Kernel`. And get this, it even works when the button scrolls off screen. I have no idea how I got it to do that.

There is just one little snag. They *AutoSave* starts as soon as the button is created. To see it notice that the clock started counting down (**not at 100 or 99 when clicked or hovered**). Please help me fix this odd behavior.

There is just one more little teeny tiny thing if you don't mind. I would like to anchor the code to a function like this `dynaSave[s_,n_]:= DynamicModule[...]`but it produces syntax errors.

```
(* dynaSave button works but oddly evaluates when created *)

Quiet@Remove["Global`*"];

DynamicModule[{
  s = 10, n = Infinity, col1 = Black, col2 = RGBColor[.2, .65, .2], 
  bg = RGBColor[.775, .85, 1]
  },
 ops := Sequence[AutoAction -> True, ImageSize -> {80, 30}, 
   Appearance -> "Palette", 
   BaseStyle -> {14, col1, Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
   Background -> bg];
 actions := (NotebookSave[];Beep[];Style["SAVED", Bold, col2]); 
 actionclock[f_, g_] := 
  Dynamic[t = f - Clock[{0, f, 1}, f, g]; If[t == 0, actions, t]];
 Button[Dynamic[x, (#) &, 
   Initialization :> (x := "DynaSave")], (x := actionclock[s, n]) &, 
  ops] 
 ]
```

Comment: On Win with 12.4+ it does not happen, that is one has to hover/click. What OS/Version are you using?

Comment: @Kuba thanks for responding. im using Windows 10. with 12.3.0. which part were you referring to? anchoring to a function or the stranger behavior of button?

Comment: This code produces a button with "DynaSave" and does not launch the action unless clicked/hovered.

Comment: To anchor the code to a function, try 'f[s_ : 10, n_ : Infinity] := 
 DynamicModule[{col1 = Black, col2 = RGBColor[.2, .65, .2],.......'

Comment: @Daniel Huber thats what i did and it produced errors. im on 12.3 with win 10.

Comment: Have you deleted the local variable definitions for s and n?

Comment: Does `AutoAction->False` change any behavior on your system? I am on M12.2-Win7 and doing as noted above requires clicking the button to start the countdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `AutoAction -> False` worked for me.

I had a couple other problems trying to fix things up though, and I ended up writing my own version of your autosaver. Feel free to use it or not; it could use improvement I'm sure (not saving unnecessarily, interval as an option, control to auto-remove cell etc.), but seems to work in 12.3.1, so I'll leave that to you. After executing, you can click on the True/False to toggle autosave.

````
Clear[autoSave];
autoSave[nb_ : SelectedNotebook[]] := 
 DynamicModule[{autoSaver, autoSaveToggle},
  autoSaver = Row[{
     Dynamic[
      Refresh[If[autoSaveToggle, NotebookSave[nb]]; 
       Framed[Style[
         Row[{"Time since last save: ", 
           Round[Now - FileDate[NotebookFileName[nb], "Modification"],
             1.1]}]]],
       UpdateInterval -> 5, TrackedSymbols :> {autoSaveToggle}]],
     Row[{"saving: ", Toggler[Dynamic@autoSaveToggle]}]
     },
    Spacer[{10, 0}]]
  , Initialize :> (autoSaver = Null; autoSaveToggle = False;)]

autoSave[]
```
````

Comment: AutoAction is for activating an action with a mouse hover. it is not the cause of an eager clock.